# Updating object value with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still a novice at js and am having a little difficulty with a function maybe someone can help me debug it...

i have an object:

```
var cart = {
    blueQty: 0,
    bluePrice: 0.00,
    blueSubtotal: 0.00,
    omniQty: 0,
    omniPrice: 0.00,
    omniSubtotal: 0.00,
    reachQty: 0,
    reachPrice: 0.00,
    reachsubtotal: 0.00,
    cartQty: 0,
    cartSubtotal: 0.00
};
```

i have a button that when clicked calls this function:

```
$(".buzzy-add-blue-to-cart-btn").click(function () {
    updateCartTotal(blueQty, 1);
});
```

The function being called is:

```
function updateCartTotal(which, addQty) {
    cart[which] += addQty;
    cart.cartQty = cart.blueQty + cart.omniQty + cart.reachQty;
    $("#cartQty").html(cart.cartQty);
    $("#cardCountInsdeModal").html(cart.cartQty);
};
```

My problem is that the quantity isnt being updated. if i change the parameter from cart.blueQty to just blueQty, it tells me blueQty isnt defined. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `updateCartTotal(blueQty, 1);` --> `updateCartTotal("blueQty", 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out...

I wasnt passing the parameter as a string. Once I corrected it to

```
$(".buzzy-add-blue-to-cart-btn").click(function () {
    updateCartTotal('blueQty', 1);
});
```

It worked fine.